# I can not sign in to Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I integrated to my app a "Google Play Services" leader board. Everything worked well, however, when I signed out from the menu of "Google Play Services" in my app, it did not sign in again. I pressed button it did do nothing. But when I cleared the app's storage, the sign in button worked. Here is my code:

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(),
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Then I am calling it from following button:

```
public void leaderButton(){
    final ImageButton btn = view.findViewById(R.id.score_btn_c);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!isSignedIn())
                 startSignInIntent();
            else showLeaderboard();

        }
    });
}
```

Below you can find the isSignedIn() method:

```
private boolean isSignedIn() {
    return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()) != null;
}
```

And additional question: I wanted to save a float number into my leader board, however, it sends the number incorrectly. For example, if my float number is 6.979, in the leader board it is showed as 0.006. In my Google console the type of leader board score is set as 1234.000 with three digits after decimal point.
Here my postScore() method:

```
public void postScore(float num){
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(getActivity(), GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()))
            .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_50), (long) num);
}
```

Comment: what does your logs say when you can't sign-in?

Comment: @noogui Thanks for your concern. The problem is that I can only sign in if the app is downloaded from google play, that's why I could not check the debug mode because Android Studio did not connected with it